# Setting a single selection in ttk::treeview

Tags: treeview, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have the following code to set selections in a `ttk::treeview` named `.wp.wf.listview`

```
if {[llength $listview_selected_in_order] > 0} {  
    puts stdout "Set $listview_selected_in_order as selection"  
    .wp.wf.listview selection set $listview_selected_in_order  
}
```

With two or more values in `$listview_selected_order` I get the following (example) output:

```
Set I2540 I2541 as selection
```

and the two items are correctly shown as selected in the treeview. However with one item selected I get this output:

```
Set IAF25 as selection
```

and no items are shown as selected in the treeview.

How can I select one item as a selection in `ttk::treeview`?
One more thing, the treeview is "`-selectmode extended`"

Comment: What happens if you run `.wp.wf.listview selection set {IAF25 IAF25}`? I.e. repeat the selected item.

Comment: the code returns     "Set IAF25 IAF25 as selection" and no items are shown as selected in the treeview

Comment: If your binding event to the tree is <Button-1> and not <<TreeviewSelect>>, this could cause the problem you're seeing. The reason is that the treeview selection is not updated in the GUI before Button-1 is released, and the <Button-1> event is a Button Down event. You have to let the treeview process the selection event before reporting what is selected. Not absolutely sure if that's your cause, because I don't see your binding setup here.

Comment: No the update occurs via a <<TreeviewSelect>> binding. Thanks anyway.